# UserProfileManager.GetChanges maximum is only 1000

Tags: 2013, user-profile, userprofilemanager

I am having a problem working with UserProfileManager.GetChanges, it seems that it has a limit of 1000, can anyone verify this? And what is the possible way to increase the cap? There seems to be lacking documentation for this on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.GetChanges(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the internals of the GetChanges method, it calls a stored procedure dbo.profile_GetUserEvents which returns 1000 records.
Another option appears to be to add a query to the GetChanges method.
Within the query there is the option of setting a ChangeTokenStart property
with a date. You can try that method.

This seems be some issue with the object model that there is no way specified or documented anywhere to get more than 1000 changes.

Comment: +1 Good answer!